# Headphones Bose SportFree as microphone on 19.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, microphone

I'm trying to use my headphones Bose SportFree as both input and output device.

I can use them perfectly as input or output device but not at same time.

If I use A2DP profile I have good audio but no microphone and if I use HFP/HSP profile then the audio is poor quality.

I tried a lot of things with blueman and pulseaudio but nothing worked so far.

I can't manage to have good audio and a microphone at same time. The final goal is to use Discord. Discord and my headphones work perfectly on my Android phone.

I am on Xubuntu 19.10 x64.

For bluetooth information the return of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` is :

```
47:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1435]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6708 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 187c:0550 Alienware Corporation AW-ELC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My Headphones are these :

https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones/soundsport-free-wireless.html#v=soundsport_free_wireless_purple

EDIT: actually I tried with another bluetooth headset and I have exactly the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please more information about your OS/System.

Comment: I added some information and edited the post